# ReactJS: Error while extracting data from JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to pass data from my JSON file to my ReactJS app, but receiving the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property `'mainPage'` of undefined

If I try to console.log `siteData` only, it will work well. I am guessing the problem is probably to do with accessing the object parameters

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my JSON object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "mainPage": {
            "navBar": ["HR", "HR1", "HR2"],
            "name": "Name one",
            "agency": "agency one"
        },

        "secondPage": {
            "rank": 2,
            "name": "Name Two",
            "agency": "agency two"
        },

        "thirdPage": {
            "rank": 3,
            "name": "Name Three",
            "agency": "agency three"
        }
    }
}
```

My .jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from '../img/company_logo.png';
import '../css/header.scss';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      siteData: {},
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('./data.json')
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          siteData: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.state);
    const { siteData } = this.state;
    console.log(siteData.data.mainPage);

    return (
      <div className="headerWrapper">
        <a href=".../public/index.html">
        <img src={logo} alt="company_logo" id="companyLogo" />
        </a>
        <ul>
          <li>Navbar_1</li>
          <li>Navbar_2</li>
          <li>Navbar_3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `siteData.data` is undefined. You are probably missing a level of nesting. Try with `siteData.mainPage`?

Comment: looks like siteData.data is undefined, please check if you are getting data using console or alert

Comment: if I console.log `siteData.data` it will show me object

Comment: must be `siteData.mainPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `render()` method of your Header component is attempting to access the `mainPage` field of `data`, which is not initially defined.

Something to keep in mind is that the components `render()` method will be called before the `axios.get()` request has completed. This typically means you'll want to render a "loading" message, or skip rendering all together (as shown below), while the `axio` request is underway.

To apply these ideas, consider revising your component as shown below:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      /* siteData: {}, Remove this */
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('./data.json')
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          siteData: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.state);
    const { siteData } = this.state;

    /* If siteData not present, then data.json has not been loaded yet, so render nothing */
    if(!siteData) {
        return null;
    }

    /* The siteData is present in the component's state, so we can now access it, and render
    as per usual */
    console.log(siteData.data.mainPage);

    return (
      <div className="headerWrapper">
        <a href=".../public/index.html">
        <img src={logo} alt="company_logo" id="companyLogo" /></a>
        <ul>
          <li>Navbar_1</li>
          <li>Navbar_2</li>
          <li>Navbar_3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `componentDidMount` runs **after** the initial render of the component. You can check the lifecycle of a component [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) where it states:

> The componentDidMount() method runs after the component output has
>   been rendered to the DOM.

In the render method you should check if this is null, as with an asynchronous (AJAX) web call, there will be no guarantee you can retrieve the data before the initial render happens, even if you call the AJAX before the render happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this? 
I have listed data statically and stored in state through setState rather than api call. 
In render, check if there's data in siteData then only map the data and you can also check by length of siteData.

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from '../img/company_logo.png';
import '../css/header.scss';

export default class Roles extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        siteData: {},
    };
}

componentDidMount = () => {
    let allData = {
        "data": {
            "mainPage": {
                "navBar": ["HR", "HR1", "HR2"],
                "name": "Name one",
                "agency": "agency one"
            },

            "secondPage": {
                "rank": 2,
                "name": "Name Two",
                "agency": "agency two"
            },

            "thirdPage": {
                "rank": 3,
                "name": "Name Three",
                "agency": "agency three"
            }
        }
    }
    this.setState({ siteData: allData.data })
}

render() {
    // console.log(this.state);
    const { siteData } = this.state;
    console.log(siteData && siteData.mainPage);

    return (
        <div className="headerWrapper">
            <a href=".../public/index.html"><img src={logo} alt="company_logo" id="companyLogo" /></a>
            <ul>
                <li>Navbar_1</li>
                <li>Navbar_2</li>
                <li>Navbar_3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```